# How to get all the names from message.mentions (discord bot)

Tags: discord, names, mention

I'm having trouble getting the names from the message.mentions string, because there can be more than one name.

I didn't find any method anywhere, message.mentions[0] doesn't work, neither does message.mentions.name or something like that.

Is there a simple way to do it?

This is what message.mentions can contain:
[<Member id=1039533025127583754 name='karlosbotospicus' discriminator='0831' bot=True nick=None guild=>, <Member id=431438830504247299 name='metrix' discriminator='4505' bot=False nick='Vašek' guild=>]

I also included the libraries I use, some of them are irrelevant to this problem

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import formatdate
from pprint import pprint
import os 
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from typing import Tuple, Any, List
import anything

from dotenv import load_dotenv  

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send(message.mentions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for menti in message.mentions:
    id = menti.id
```